# Is there a word for a word that someone hears often but never has learned the real definition to?

Tags: single-word-requests

1. Is there a word for a word that someone hears often but never has learned the formal definition to and can only guess the meaning of from the contexts it has been used in? I know I've been in the position in which I've heard a word used so often I haven't consulted a dictionary and so I didn't know the real definition and would struggle every time I heard it to figure out what it means really.
2. An offshoot of my question is: is there a word for a word that someone thinks one knows the definition to, but is actually incorrect? I've also seen this phenomenon a lot, where someone thinks he knows the definition and uses it just incorrectly enough for me to tell he doesn't really know what it means.

Comment: Can you write an example sentence where this word would be used?

Comment: Cargo cult if used? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is two questions, and you shouldn't post two questions under the same post, it will just cause confusion.  Anyway:

Re 2., you could call it a ***misapprehension***, which means that you think you understand something when actually you have the wrong idea.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/misapprehension